# how to nest an array inside an object in yaml?

Tags: json, yaml

suppose you have a `Map<String, Object>` called "something" in YAML

```
something:
```

and the corresponding JSON should look like this:
**json**

```
 "something": {
      "else": "then",
      "array": [
         "element in array"
       ]
    }
```

so for this yaml spec might  be:

```
something:
  else: then
  array: 
    - element in array
```

but since `something` is a Map it does not let me do

```
array: 
  - element in array
```

or this

```
array: ['element in array']
```

so the question is what should be the yaml to get the above mentioned JSON considering `something` is a `Map<String, Object>` is it possible?

This is regarding the defining of the ServiceCatalogDefinition for the implementation of OpenServiceBroker API.

[OSB Catalog using Yaml](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-open-service-broker/docs/current/reference/html5/index.html#providing-a-catalog-using-properties)

[OSB Catalog json looks like this](https://github.com/openservicebrokerapi/servicebroker/blob/master/spec.md#input-parameters-schema-object)

I am trying to make the "properties" mentioned in schemas in the above link as required.
for that I need to make it return the json like this:

```
"properties" : {
  "someProperty" : {
      "description": "description",
      "type": "string"
   },
  "required": [
    "someProperty"
   ]    
}
```

And the yaml does validation in my application.yml throwing the error mentioned in comment

Comment: Not sure what is required here. Are you looking to convert Json to Yml programmatically?

Comment: what should the yaml be so that the I can get the above mentioned JSON.

Comment: Yaml you mentioned is the correct one. It didnt give error in yaml parser

Comment: Your YAML is correct, however your JSON misses a comma after `"then"`. Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: Sorry I missed the comma, that was not the problem.

Comment: I get the error expected an object but found a sequence Since something is a Map<String, Object> it is not letting me do exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the site [json2yaml](https://www.json2yaml.com/), you get YAML :

```
---
something:
  else: then
  array:
  - element in array
```

from the json :

```
{  
  "something": {
      "else": "then",
      "array": [
         "element in array"
       ]
    } 
}
```

Compare to you, I think it's your "-" must be to the same level as "array".

Comment: Adding a directives end marker in your YAML, when you don't have directive, nor have an empty document, doesn't really make sense without further explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried this solution. I get the error `expected an object but found a sequence` Since **something** is a Map<String, Object> it is not letting me do exactly this.

Comment: Strange, I tryed in a dropwizard project and I have no error... With what you parse your YAML? What give you the error?

Comment: SnakeYaml. Sorry I did not respond since I resorted to specifying the Catalog spec I mentioned in the question as a java configuration bean. I don't need the answer anymore. But it would great to learn.

Answer (score 0):

There is two things you need to do:

- make the JSON valid, e.g. by inserting a comma (as @flyx suggests) and adding curly braces around the root level object:

  ```
  { 
    "something": {
      "else": "then",
      "array": [
        "element in array"
      ]
    } 
  }
  ```
- change the plain scalar (i.e. without quotes) mapping key `something`, to a double quoted scalar:

  ```
  { 
    "something": {
      "else": "then",
      "array": [
        "element in array"
      ]
    } 
  }
  ```

Since YAML has, for all practical purposes, effectively been a superset of JSON (since YAML 1.2 from 2009), you don't need to do anything else. And of course you can read the above with both a YAML loader, as well as with a JSON parser.

Comment: I had missed the comma in the question by mistake. Thanks for pointing out. I tried @Ehcnalb mentioned it did not work. I get the following error `expected an object but found a sequence` since **something** is a Map<String, Object> I tried double quoting the key **something** also it did not work. Just to give some more context I have added details in the question.